# How to delete items from dataitem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, dataitem

How do I delete items from a DataItem wpf c#?
What happens, is the following:

I fill a DataGrid with a DataItem

```
public class DataItem
{
public String Column1 {get; set};
public String Column2 {get; set};
public String Column3 {get; set};
public String Column4 {get; set};
public String Column5 {get; set};
}

DataGrid.Items.Add(new DataItem {Column1 = val1, Column2 = val2, Column3 = val3, Column4 = cantidad});
```

Then I print the columns that I want the DataGrid in a ticket with a FOREACH cycle

```
foreach (DataItem row in DataGrid.Items)
{
string quantity = row.Column4;
product string = row.Column2;
string amount = row.Column5;

ticket.AddItem (quantity, product, amount);
}
```

To remove items from the datagrid I do with a button

```
DataGrid.Items.Clear ();
```

Until there all right, add new elements to the DataGrid.

The problem is when I want to print new data in the DataGrid, because print the new data and the already-deleted data.

How do I eliminate definitively the DataItem data, when I clean the DataGrid?

In WindowsForms I do the same, with the syntax of C# and everything works excellent

Comment: It might help.Check delete operation in this article.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30905/WPF-DataGrid-Practical-Examples

Comment: Please dont use CAPSLOCK to questions